# Why can't an <h1> element appear as a descendant of a <th> element?

Tags: html, html-table

I was trying to create a table but when using h1 and h2 elements as descendants of a th element, the code validator tells me it can't be this way. Can you please tell me how could it be fixed?

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">
      <h1>Wine Festival Schedule</h1>
     </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <h2>Time</h2>
    </th>
    <th>
      <h2>Event</h2>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

[image: Error message image]

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th): "Permitted content: ... no header, footer, sectioning, ..."

Comment: If you want to make your HTML compliant to the checker you are using you simply can not do this. You can however use a `span` and give it a header styling instead or directly style the `th`.

Comment: A `th` is already a header element. No need to insert another one inside it

Comment: `<th colspan="2" class="largeText">Wine Festival Schedule</th>`

Comment: @mousetail Your comment is the most direct, to the point and correct answer and you should make it one.

Answer (score 0):

In short, HTML [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org) does not allow this.

Longer version below:

The `th` element content model is (reference [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-th-element)):

Flow content, but with no header, footer, sectioning content, or **heading content descendants**.

Heading content: (reference [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#heading-content-2))

Heading content defines the heading of a section (whether explicitly marked up using sectioning content elements, or implied by the heading content itself).

`h1` `h2` `h3` `h4` `h5` `h6` `hgroup` (if it has a descendant h1 to h6 element)

This means that `h1` to `h6` as well as `hgroup` are not meant to be used with in `th`